# How to set CSS for the php script loaded by Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a js function as below:

```
 function show() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#container').load('show_my_file.php');
          $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">').attr('href','show_my_file.css') );
      })
 }
```

This function is supposed to load the show_my_file.css to render #container (which now loads show_my_file.php), but it didn't work.

Does anybody how to how solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: put quotes around the filename `show_my_file.php`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn sorry, the quote is a typo. still not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only thing i see wrong is the load(show_my_file.php); it should be

```
$('#container').load('show_my_file.php');
```

it worked with for me.

Comment: sorry, the quote is a typo. still not working, any idea?

Comment: i have tested your code an it works. mabe you are not calling jquery.  add this on your head. <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $('#container').load("show_my_file.php");
```

The file or path to the file should be in quote " "

Comment: i started answer and before click publish it appeared yours, as you ended sooner, should i delete my post?

Comment: @BlackPearl sorry, the quote is a typo. still not working, any idea?

Comment: Is the part to the file correct? If yes, try testing it on firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function show() {
      $('#container').load('show_my_file.php');
      $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">').attr('href','show_my_file.css') );
   }
});
```